# How to get a notification when someone hashtagged me in a post in Yammer?

Tags: notifications, hashtag, yammer

I'm using Yammer developer REST API. I want to get a notification, when someone hashtagged me in their post. I went through [REST API documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/), but couldn't figure out which API operation can be used for this. Can someone help me to figure that out please? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

It seems I can retrieve notifications using [GET Notifications](https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-notifications) operation, and filter required events. What I want to know is if there's a way to get an event-trigger fired (basically a push message) when I'm hashtagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to get a notification when you are mentioned in a message. Those messages just end up in your inbox.

It's not a great answer, but you could poll the inbox on some interval with these REST API calls:

```
GET /api/v1/messages/inbox
GET /api/v1/messages/inbox?newer_than=[:message_id]
```

where `:message_id` is the highest id of the messages you have received.

Keep in mind that you don't want to poll too often or you'll hit the rate limit.